# Android Gallery App

Tags: android, performance

I have written this code to run on android. It gets all the images from android and place them in a Grid view. When i use the same images without scaling down it says the device is low on memory. when i do scale down the images it says application stopped.

```
   This also says in the logcat (The application is doing too much work at its first activity.)
```

Error is at this Line

```
 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
```

below is the rest of the code. Please help me with this problem or give me any idea to make a Gallery just like the android built in Gallery that is as much fast and resposive.

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {

        imageView = new ImageView(activity);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
    }
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Android gallery app may be loading the thumbnail of those images rather than loading the original image.

Comment: @MidhunMP I am scanning the whole FileSystem to scan for JPEG and PNG files and load them by myself. So it definitely is not loading thumbnails. There is some problem but i can't seem to figure it out. If you could help me please and you can give me some suggestions to make it even better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing a trace it's hard to tell where your application is spending all it's time. From the sounds of it you're converting and re sizing all the images on the MainThread, which is locking up your application.

I recommend using a library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to take care of loading the images into the imageviews for you. Be sure to resize the images as well. You'll end up with something like the following

```
Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .fromFile(fileName)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(myImageView)
```

Another alternative is [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), which is very similar to Glide.

Comment: it uses 75 MB of my RAM. The scrolling is too slow. I Run it on Galaxy S4 i9505 GT. What could be the problem?

Comment: @SalmanAli I'd say there's too many images being shown, if you analyze your heap dump you should be able to find the culprits

Comment: Thanks i have read about Asynchronous events and implemented that concept and my application is working perfectly fine. Thanks though thank you very much.